# Change unallocated partition position without losing data

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I have an issue where I can't extend the Linux Filesystem partition to utilize the 20GB Unallocated partition.

[The filesystem partition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5D2t.png) | [The unallocated partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdHHh.png)

As I understand the 20gb unallocated partition has to be to the right side of the linux filesystem partition, and currently it is on its left side.

How can I move the unallocated partition to the right side and then resize the system partition to consume it without losing data?

Comment: Unallocated space is exactly what its name suggests and NOT a partition. In your specific case you have an additional problem, a small ~1GB NTFS partition between the unallocated space and the partition you want to add that space to. So, before anything else **have BACKUPS**. Then consider if you really need that small NTFS partition because if not then you better delete it and then only "move to the left" one partition instead of two. ANY PARTITION MOVE IS RISKY. And, of course, you need to do it from a live session.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to move partition 5 and 6 to the left in order to be able to extend partition 6 (as it will only extend to the right size of a partition as you already know). Moving partitions always have a certain risk of dataloss, so make backups first.